# Add style of class only for first element of UL (JS or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have page where `ul` is displayed on the page as shown below:

```
<ul>
    <li style="width: 158px;">A</li>
    <li style="width: 158px;">B</li>
    <li style="width: 158px;">C</li>
</ul>
```

Can I add style border or class only for first element A (using JS or jQuery or any other framework)?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer CSS:

```
ul li:first-child {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

If you prefer JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li')[0].style.border = '1px solid red';
```

If you prefer jQuery:

```
$('ul li').first().css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to add a class to the first element of the `<ul/>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li:first').addClass('has-border');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e8pvj9hb/

Answer (score 0):

This will target the first occurrence of an `<li>` and apply a border to it.

`document.querySelectorAll('li')[0].style.border = '1px solid #ccc';`

If you want to only target the first `<li>` with a specific class, you can change the `('li')` to something like `('li.someClass')` and put a class on the element you wish to target.

If you also wish to target all of your `li` elements, then use something like this.

`document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(x) {
  x.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
})`